# FCM getToken is not a function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I am trying to develop push notification while following Google FCM Docs.

Follwing codes are literally first step

1. add and initialize the FCM SDK.

2. configure web credentials

I think 1st one is work well, but 2nd one is not working.

The error says "messaging is not a function"

I tried downgrade version of cdn but it didn't worked.

Is there any information about this?

```js
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.3/firebase-app.js";
import { getMessaging } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.3/firebase-messaging.js";
const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "---",
      authDomain: "---",
      projectId: "---",
      storageBucket: "---",
      messagingSenderId: "---",
      appId: "---"
};

      // add and initialize the FCM SDK.
      const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      const messaging = getMessaging(app);

      // configure web credentials
      // error
      messaging.getToken({ vapidKey: "---" });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.3/firebase-messaging.js";
const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseConfig);
getToken(messaging , {vapidKey: "---").then(token => console.log(token));
```